# Limit access to posts/pages by user roles

Tags: plugins, posts, functions, user-roles, user-access

I'm looking for a way to protect content by user roles.

Example:

you have to be registered to view posts (frontend).

If a user is a subscriber he can read post 1, 2 and 3, but if the user is a contributor he can view post 1,2,3 and 4,5,6...

does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I haven't used this personally you are probably looking at a plugin [like this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-access-manager/)

Seems to provide all the functionality you have requested above.

Comment: I've just tried this one. Doesnt do what I need, but almost... or.... to complicated!!

Comment: I've just installed the plugin and it's very easy to set up access to certain posts for subscribers and then give more access to contributors.

Comment: yes, backend, but I need to define access frontend. Who can or can not read posts, defined bu user roles.

Comment: Yes you can do that with the plug in (See screenshot at http://s.wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-access-manager/screenshot-4.jpg?r=580686)

Comment: No problems, Glad you found it in the end! :)

Answer (score 4):

you can use such conditions to show private posts only to logged in users with role `contributor`. Now you only need to make post [`private`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Content_Visibility#Private_Content) to make that post available for contributor.

```
<?php 
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        $private = get_post_custom_values("private");
        if (isset($private[0]) && $private == "true") {

            if ( current_user_can( 'contributor' ) ) { //passing role to it may sometime not work
            the_title();
            the_content();
            } else {            // text to show instead the post
                echo 'this post is private, only contributor can view it';
            }

        } else {        // this is visible to all
            the_title();
            the_content();
        }

    endwhile; 
    endif; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve something like that you can make some posts private and show them just to the logged in users, first you need to add a custom field, you can name it "private" and value it "True". Then add replace the default WP loop with this code snippet:

```
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

    $private = get_post_custom_values("private");
    if (isset($private[0]) && $private == "true") {
        if (is_user_logged_in()) {
            // Display private post to logged user
        }
    } else {
        // Display public post to everyone
    }

endwhile; endif; ?>
```